# my contact form php won't send an email via smtp to my gmail account

Tags: php, email, smtp, send

I am trying to insert the php code SMTP via gmail so it can send through smtp.gmail.com, and it doesn't seem to work. I someone can give me a hand so I can get it working, it would be a great help.

p.s. with out this scrpit it works on a server that already has the smtp setup. I am trying to insert it so I can use it on another server with out mail server.

```
  `($host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "<wilkinsonsport2014@gmail.com>";
$password = "********";)`
```

`

```
    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "<wilkinsonsport2014@gmail.com>";
$password = "********";

$mail_to = 'wilkinsonsport2014@gmail.com'; 

$name = $_POST['sender-name'];
$mail_from = $_POST['sender-email'];
$phone = $_POST['sender-phone'];
$message = $_POST['sender-message'];

$subject = 'localhost/wilkinson-sport Messaggio da un visitatore ' . $name;

$body_message .= 'Da: ' . $name . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Telfono: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Commenti: ' . $message;


$headers .= 'Da: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Rispondi a: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers); 

if ($mail_sent == true){ 

if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['accetto'] == "si")
{               
    echo ("<script>alert('Hai accettato il consenso privacy.')</script>");
}
else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['accetto'] == "no")
{
    echo ("<script>alert('Non hai accettato il consenso privacy. Riprova!')</script>");
}
else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['entra'] == false)
{
    echo ("<script>alert('Devi accettare il consenso privacy per accedere!')</script>");
} 
} 


?>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using PHPMailer, a class for mail transfers https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Exactly! I think that problem OP described has something to do with TLS. I've seen SO posts about problems with gmail that were solved using PHPMailer.

Comment: I think you should, with little effort. Look at PHPMailer documentation. It's very easy to use.

Comment: how do i create a PHPMailer instance?

Comment: for a new instance `$mail = new PHPMailer;`
here is ["A Simple Example"](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: yesh i see, i've tried it and still doesn't work. Taking off this piece of script ($host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "<wilkinsonsport2014@gmail.com>";
$password = "********";) The rest of the code works perfectly on a mail server, which i have it in my site in a online webserver. I want to use the rest of the code but add the smtp code to use it on another site on another server that doesn't have a mail server.

Comment: $username = "<wilkinsonsport2014@gmail.com>" try without < > like "wilkinsonsport2014@gmail.com" directly